# Inline translation magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0.7, inline-translations

So I am using the inline translation. But for some reason everytime I change things it doesn't update. I refresh the page, I delete the cache,... Non of it is working. How can I fix this?

[image: Image Where I change it]

Comment: Have you check console or log file. is there any error?

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: In directory at Magento Root/var/log. If any error is occured then it show in that files and it help you to solve problem.

Comment: [2016-10-22 20:40:31] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://mydomain/itron.php","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-10-22 20:40:31] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://mydomain/itron.php","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-10-22 20:40:38] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://mydomain/itron.php","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Comment: I Think this is the error